# What PHP code is causing Admin Ajax Load More 500 Error in WordPress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, php-8

I have a WordPress page that loads thumbnails of audio tracks using ajax. So as I scroll down the page it loads more rows of thumbnails. After switching to PHP 8 I am getting the following JS error in the console when I scroll down the page.

`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax_load_more&paged=8&arg%5Bpost_type%5D=track&arg%5Borderby%5D=date&arg%5Border%5D=DESC&arg%5Bposts_per_page%5D=12&arg%5Btpl%5D=templates%2Floop%2Flist-music.php&arg%5Bdisplay%5D=item-grid&arg%5Bcolumn%5D=6&arg%5Bmedia_size%5D=thumbnail&arg%5Bmore%5D=scroll&arg%5Bcache_time%5D=12&arg%5Barg%5D%5Btax_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Btaxonomy%5D=track_genre&arg%5Barg%5D%5Btax_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=slug&arg%5Barg%5D%5Btax_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bterms%5D=teachers-aid&arg%5Btax_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Btaxonomy%5D=track_genre&arg%5Btax_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=slug&arg%5Btax_query%5D%5B0%5D%5Bterms%5D=teachers-aid&arg%5Bajax%5D=1&arg%5Bpaged%5D=7`

When I look at my error log I see the following:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home/jack1/public_html/wp-content/themes/pulsetheme/includes/widgets/class-ff-widget-post.php(115): include()
#1 /home/jack1/public_html/wp-includes/widgets.php(1257): Post_Widget->widget(Array, Array)
#2 /home/jack1/public_html/wp-content/themes/pulsetheme/includes/widgets/class-ff-widget-post.php(643): the_widget('post_widget', Array)
#3 /home/jack1/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): ajax_load_more('')
#4 /home/jack1/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#5 /home/jack1/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#6 /home/jack1/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(203): do_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in /home/jack1/public_html/wp-content/themes/pulsetheme-child-theme/templates/loop/list-music.php on line 40
```

This is the code located on line 40 of the list-music.php file:

`<?php echo esc_html( FF()->duration( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'duration', true )/1000, null, true ) ); ?>`

If I change the code on line 40 to the following code below, it stills throws a 500 error.

`<?php echo esc_html( FF()->duration( intdiv(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'duration', true ), 1000), null, true ) ); ?>`

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to debugging JS errors. I'm not even sure which file I should start looking at to debug the issue.

If anyone can point me into the right direction I will be able to take it from there. Thank you.

Comment: Replace the current code with new one below.    intdiv is not a function here by default in WordPress if you are using any custom function for calling then firstly assigned a value in variable then put inside a function argument.


$duration = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'duration', true );

<?php echo esc_html( FF()->duration( int($duration , 1000), null, true ) ); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with help from a commenter.

```
<?php $duration = fdiv(intval(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'duration', true )), 1000); echo esc_html( FF()->duration( $duration, null, true ) ); ?>
```